# Diamonds in new Safari on macOS Mojave are too large

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, moderators, safari

Apple released macOS Mojave yesterday, and not only does it come with a Dark Mode, it also enlarges the moderators' diamonds (♦):

[image]

For comparison, here is how it looks like on Chrome, and how it looked like in Safari before the update.

[image]

I hope it's possible to change the font or something, so that they become normal size again.

Comment: We've been dealing with giant diamonds on Android for years. Welcome to the club. ;)

Comment: And giant *orange-red* diamonds on Android instead of proper blue. :-(